# Unable to spawn Gazebo from terminal

Tags: gazebo, installation, ignition-fortress

I installed Gazebo Fortress following the instructions [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu) on my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I was able to install it without any problems & I could see the app installed with the name `Ignition Gazebo 6`. I am able to spawn it and run shapes.sdf file.

But when I try to spawn it using `gz sim shapes.sdf` from [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/getstarted#step-2-run), it doesn't work. Here's the output I get:

```
This tool modifies various aspects of a running Gazebo simulation.

  Usage:  gz <command>

List of commands:

  help      Print this help text.
  camera    Control a camera
  debug     Returns completion list for a command. Used for bash completion.
  help      Outputs information about a command
  joint     Modify properties of a joint
  log       Introspects and manipulates Gazebo log files.
  marker    Add, modify, or delete visual markers
  model     Modify properties of a model
  physics   Modify properties of the physics engine
  sdf       Converts between SDF versions, and provides info about SDF files
  stats     Print statistics about a running gzserver instance.
  topic     Lists information about topics on a Gazebo master
  world     Modify world properties


Use "gz help <command>" to print help for a command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gazebo Fortress, you should use the command `ign gazebo shapes.sdf`. For Gazebo Garden and newer, you can use `gz sim ...`. This is because the Gazebo project changed names from Ignition to Gazebo after Fortress was released.

Comment: I knew about replacing `gz` with `ign` but didn't know I had to replace `sim` too in the `gz sim ...` command.

Thanks for that!