# Unable to install ros-gz on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine with ROS2 Iron already installed

Tags: ignition-fortress, ros-iron, ros-gazebo

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 laptop with ROS2 Iron already installed. Now, I am trying to install Gazebo Fortress (as it is the recommended version for my configuration - mentioned [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/ros_installation)). I ran `sudo apt-get install ros-iron-ros-gz` but I am getting the below errors (see the end of the output). Kindly help me in going about this. Thanks!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ignition-transport11-cli libdart-collision-bullet-dev libdart-collision-ode-dev libdart-collision-ode6.12 libdart-external-ikfast-dev libdart-utils-dev
  libdart-utils-urdf-dev libdart-utils-urdf6.12 libignition-common4 libignition-common4-av libignition-common4-av-dev libignition-common4-core-dev
  libignition-common4-dev libignition-common4-events libignition-common4-events-dev libignition-common4-graphics libignition-common4-graphics-dev
  libignition-common4-profiler libignition-common4-profiler-dev libignition-fuel-tools7 libignition-fuel-tools7-dev libignition-gazebo6 libignition-gazebo6-dev
  libignition-gazebo6-plugins libignition-gui6 libignition-gui6-dev libignition-math6-eigen3-dev libignition-msgs8 libignition-msgs8-dev libignition-physics5
  libignition-physics5-bullet libignition-physics5-bullet-dev libignition-physics5-core-dev libignition-physics5-dartsim libignition-physics5-dartsim-dev
  libignition-physics5-dev libignition-physics5-heightmap-dev libignition-physics5-mesh-dev libignition-physics5-sdf-dev libignition-physics5-tpe
  libignition-physics5-tpe-dev libignition-physics5-tpelib libignition-physics5-tpelib-dev libignition-plugin libignition-plugin-dev libignition-rendering6
  libignition-rendering6-core-dev libignition-rendering6-dev libignition-rendering6-ogre1 libignition-rendering6-ogre1-dev libignition-rendering6-ogre2
  libignition-rendering6-ogre2-dev libignition-sensors6 libignition-sensors6-air-pressure libignition-sensors6-air-pressure-dev libignition-sensors6-altimeter
  libignition-sensors6-altimeter-dev libignition-sensors6-boundingbox-camera libignition-sensors6-boundingbox-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-camera
  libignition-sensors6-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-core-dev libignition-sensors6-depth-camera libignition-sensors6-depth-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-dev
  libignition-sensors6-force-torque libignition-sensors6-force-torque-dev libignition-sensors6-gpu-lidar libignition-sensors6-gpu-lidar-dev libignition-sensors6-imu
  libignition-sensors6-imu-dev libignition-sensors6-lidar libignition-sensors6-lidar-dev libignition-sensors6-logical-camera libignition-sensors6-logical-camera-dev
  libignition-sensors6-magnetometer libignition-sensors6-magnetometer-dev libignition-sensors6-navsat libignition-sensors6-navsat-dev libignition-sensors6-rendering
  libignition-sensors6-rendering-dev libignition-sensors6-rgbd-camera libignition-sensors6-rgbd-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-segmentation-camera
  libignition-sensors6-segmentation-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-thermal-camera libignition-sensors6-thermal-camera-dev libignition-tools-dev
  libignition-transport11 libignition-transport11-core-dev libignition-transport11-dev libignition-transport11-log libignition-transport11-log-dev
  libignition-transport11-parameters libignition-transport11-parameters-dev libignition-utils1 libignition-utils1-cli-dev libignition-utils1-dev libogre-next-dev
  libogrenexthlmspbs2.2.5 libogrenexthlmsunlit2.2.5 libogrenextmain2.2.5 libogrenextmeshlodgenerator2.2.5 libogrenextoverlay2.2.5 libogrenextplanarreflections2.2.5
  libogrenextsceneformat2.2.5 libqt5charts5 libqt5location5 libqt5location5-plugins libqt5positioning5-plugins libqt5positioningquick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5
  libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libsdformat12 libsdformat12-dev liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-model-state3.0 liburdfdom-sensor3.0
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtcharts qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtlocation
  qml-module-qtpositioning qml-module-qtqml qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qtquickcontrols2-5-dev
  ros-iron-actuator-msgs ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-image-transport-plugins ros-iron-ros-gz-bridge
  ros-iron-ros-gz-image ros-iron-ros-gz-interfaces ros-iron-ros-gz-sim ros-iron-ros-gz-sim-demos ros-iron-sdformat-urdf ros-iron-theora-image-transport
  sdformat12-sdf
Suggested packages:
  ogre-next-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ignition-transport11-cli libdart-collision-bullet-dev libdart-collision-ode-dev libdart-collision-ode6.12 libdart-external-ikfast-dev libdart-utils-dev
  libdart-utils-urdf-dev libdart-utils-urdf6.12 libignition-common4 libignition-common4-av libignition-common4-av-dev libignition-common4-core-dev
  libignition-common4-dev libignition-common4-events libignition-common4-events-dev libignition-common4-graphics libignition-common4-graphics-dev
  libignition-common4-profiler libignition-common4-profiler-dev libignition-fuel-tools7 libignition-fuel-tools7-dev libignition-gazebo6 libignition-gazebo6-dev
  libignition-gazebo6-plugins libignition-gui6 libignition-gui6-dev libignition-math6-eigen3-dev libignition-msgs8 libignition-msgs8-dev libignition-physics5
  libignition-physics5-bullet libignition-physics5-bullet-dev libignition-physics5-core-dev libignition-physics5-dartsim libignition-physics5-dartsim-dev
  libignition-physics5-dev libignition-physics5-heightmap-dev libignition-physics5-mesh-dev libignition-physics5-sdf-dev libignition-physics5-tpe
  libignition-physics5-tpe-dev libignition-physics5-tpelib libignition-physics5-tpelib-dev libignition-plugin libignition-plugin-dev libignition-rendering6
  libignition-rendering6-core-dev libignition-rendering6-dev libignition-rendering6-ogre1 libignition-rendering6-ogre1-dev libignition-rendering6-ogre2
  libignition-rendering6-ogre2-dev libignition-sensors6 libignition-sensors6-air-pressure libignition-sensors6-air-pressure-dev libignition-sensors6-altimeter
  libignition-sensors6-altimeter-dev libignition-sensors6-boundingbox-camera libignition-sensors6-boundingbox-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-camera
  libignition-sensors6-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-core-dev libignition-sensors6-depth-camera libignition-sensors6-depth-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-dev
  libignition-sensors6-force-torque libignition-sensors6-force-torque-dev libignition-sensors6-gpu-lidar libignition-sensors6-gpu-lidar-dev libignition-sensors6-imu
  libignition-sensors6-imu-dev libignition-sensors6-lidar libignition-sensors6-lidar-dev libignition-sensors6-logical-camera libignition-sensors6-logical-camera-dev
  libignition-sensors6-magnetometer libignition-sensors6-magnetometer-dev libignition-sensors6-navsat libignition-sensors6-navsat-dev libignition-sensors6-rendering
  libignition-sensors6-rendering-dev libignition-sensors6-rgbd-camera libignition-sensors6-rgbd-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-segmentation-camera
  libignition-sensors6-segmentation-camera-dev libignition-sensors6-thermal-camera libignition-sensors6-thermal-camera-dev libignition-tools-dev
  libignition-transport11 libignition-transport11-core-dev libignition-transport11-dev libignition-transport11-log libignition-transport11-log-dev
  libignition-transport11-parameters libignition-transport11-parameters-dev libignition-utils1 libignition-utils1-cli-dev libignition-utils1-dev libogre-next-dev
  libogrenexthlmspbs2.2.5 libogrenexthlmsunlit2.2.5 libogrenextmain2.2.5 libogrenextmeshlodgenerator2.2.5 libogrenextoverlay2.2.5 libogrenextplanarreflections2.2.5
  libogrenextsceneformat2.2.5 libqt5charts5 libqt5location5 libqt5location5-plugins libqt5positioning5-plugins libqt5positioningquick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5
  libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libsdformat12 libsdformat12-dev liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-model-state3.0 liburdfdom-sensor3.0
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtcharts qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtlocation
  qml-module-qtpositioning qml-module-qtqml qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qtquickcontrols2-5-dev
  ros-iron-actuator-msgs ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-iron-compressed-image-transport ros-iron-image-transport-plugins ros-iron-ros-gz
  ros-iron-ros-gz-bridge ros-iron-ros-gz-image ros-iron-ros-gz-interfaces ros-iron-ros-gz-sim ros-iron-ros-gz-sim-demos ros-iron-sdformat-urdf
  ros-iron-theora-image-transport sdformat12-sdf
0 upgraded, 150 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,354 kB/31.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 204 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-compressed-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-theora-image-transport amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-image-transport-plugins amd64 3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-ros-gz-bridge amd64 0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.114732
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-ros-gz-image amd64 0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.120950
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-ros-gz-sim amd64 0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.103229
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-ros-gz-sim-demos amd64 0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.121601
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 ros-iron-ros-gz amd64 0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.121640
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112549_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport/ros-iron-compressed-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.112554_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-theora-image-transport/ros-iron-theora-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.110033_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins/ros-iron-image-transport-plugins_3.1.0-1jammy.20231117.114631_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-ros-gz-bridge/ros-iron-ros-gz-bridge_0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.114732_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-ros-gz-image/ros-iron-ros-gz-image_0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.120950_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-ros-gz-sim/ros-iron-ros-gz-sim_0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.103229_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-ros-gz-sim-demos/ros-iron-ros-gz-sim-demos_0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.121601_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-iron-ros-gz/ros-iron-ros-gz_0.247.0-1jammy.20231117.121640_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same set up as yours, except Gazebo Harmonic instead of Fortress. The link you posted looked to be the correct guide, however I didn't use the `sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz` example, as it indicated it was for older versions of ros but might not be the case for Iron specifically.

Did you look at the guide with the installation of Fortress on Ubuntu? It's in the same domain as the guide you followed, here's the link: https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu

Based on your output, it looks like there's an issue with fetching those packages as they aren't accessible to install on your Ubuntu VM, unless you have the necessary keyrings. In the link I posted, it has copyable commands to set up your keyrings and install Ignition Fortress.

All you have to do is follow the new link I gave, and you should be good to go.

It may be possible that it won't install due to other conflicting packages, requiring some sort of additional `sudo apt update/(auto)clean/(auto)remove` command. Additionally, as the link indicates, Ignition Gazebo isn't compatible with Gazebo-classic (Gazebo11), so Gazebo-classic may require uninstallation. Either way, I think whatever new problems emerge can be fairly intuitive to figure out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually installed gazebo-fortress using the link you included. But even there I was facing some minor issue (I posted it here (https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107374/unable-to-spawn-gazebo-from-terminal)).

But I went ahead & tried installing ros-gz from source following this: https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/iron#from-source. Still I get the same Error 404 for a few packages like `ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you tried uninstalling gazebo-fortress in full? Including other packages that it was depending on? From what I understand source or binary installation should work.

It may be possible that when you tried installing ros-gz from source, it is conflicting with what was installed via packages. Try listing necessary packages, i.e. ```dpkg -l | grep ros-gz``` and uninstall whichever package, then reinstall again.

Comment: I started using docker eventually. Thanks for your time!